# UCWA - different results for different applications

Tags: skype-for-business, ucwa, skypedeveloper

I'm playing with the interactive web sdk at https://ucwa.skype.com/websdk. I'm signed in successfully with a Azure AD login. With the F12 Tool I can see, that I have got a valid oauth token.

Now I take this token and trying to get a person object via a GET request like this: _https://webpoolam30e08.infra.lync.com/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/113782897528/me

This is the result:

```
{
 "uri": "sip:xxx@yyy.de",
 "name": "john doe",
 "_links": {
   "self": {
     "href": "/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/111364079681/me"
   }
 },
 "rel": "me"
```

}

What I expect are more information about me like this:

```
{
  "uri": "sip:xxx@yyy.de",
  "name": "john doe",
  "emailAddresses": [
    "xxx"
  ],
  "company": "my company name",
  "workPhoneNumber": "tel:+123456789",
  "endpointUri": "sip:xxx;opaque=user:epid:4JNzkgeuabct-CSuIgYV8gAA;gruu",
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/113782897528/me"
    },
    "note": {
      "href": "/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/113782897528/me/note"
    },
    "presence": {
      "href": "/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/113782897528/me/presence"
    },
    "location": {
      "href": "/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/113782897528/me/location"
    },
    "reportMyActivity": {
      "href": "/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/113782897528/me/reportMyActivity"
    },
    "photo": {
      "href": "/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/113782897528/photos/xxxx"
    }
  },
  "rel": "me"
}
```

I found out that the result depends on the application id. If I open the Office365 web portal (_https://outlook.office.com/owa) and search for an valid application id with the F12 tool, then I get the expected result. Even with the OAuth token that I got from the interactive web sdk example. So this can not be an security or permission issue?? 
I grant access to all permissions in the azure management portal.

Also very strange is that I get different status codes with the same oauth token for this two very similar request

_https://webpoolam30e08.infra.lync.com/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/**113782897528**/me/presence

-> 200 OK

_https://webpoolam30e08.infra.lync.com/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/**112861033140**/me/presence

-> 403 Forbidden

```
{
  "code": "Forbidden",
  "message": "The requested operation isn't allowed."
}
```

So why is there a difference between both applications and what is required to get the same results? Is anything missing in the azure configuration?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

UCWA and to a larger extent Skype for Business Online are in a preview phase which may help explain why you are seeing a different result set between the two applications.  When logging into the O365 portal as your user you are most likely getting supplemental information from Exchange or the portal is able to receive more information from UCWA using internal APIs (and permissions) not publicly exposed.

If I remember correctly and your request example above is a follows:

- /ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/113782897528/me/presence - O365 Portal
- /ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/112861033140/me/presence - Non-Portal

What you are seeing is that Presence is not currently enabled (a better term might be the API is not publicly exposed) for UCWA when using Online clients.

Answer (score 1):

Access to presence is available in preview mode through the "Read/write Skype user information (preview)" Delegated Permission.  You might not have access to it, but here's a picture of what it looks like in Azure AD if you do:

[image: SfB Online Permissions]

I created a UCWA-based native app that connects to SfB Online and allows you to set your presence:

https://github.com/tamhinsf/ucwa-sfbo-console

Just follow the README to register your own app and plug in your settings into my code.  I output the result of each API call onto the console so you can see what's going on.

I've also made fork of the Interactive Web SDK Samples you've been using that consolidates the Azure AD settings into a single file.  You might want a local copy to more closely inspect and modify the calls:

https://github.com/tamhinsf/skype-web-sdk-samples

Answer (score 0):

Sharing the token like that between applications seems like a security violation. The token is provided for a specific resource and the server likely validates that the token you are providing matches the scopes that the application was created with.
What scenario are you trying to perform by sharing the token?